# When is it safe to programatically access fragment view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I''m trying to grab the listview widget on two of my fragments, but essentailly anywhere I put this code, my compiler tells me that it will produce a null pointer error:

```
    ListView list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tasksList);
    list.setAdapter(GroupContentActivity.tasksAdapter);
```

tasksAdapter should be a static arrayAdapter kept in the main activity.

Where can I put this code so that it connects the adapter to the list as soon as the fragments are made? The two fragments are kept in a fragment tab host.

Also, it doesn't seem to be able to find my tasksAdapter, I'm sure I'm just having a brain fart, but what am I doing wrong?

It is declared outside of any methods like so:

```
private static ArrayAdapter<String> tasksAdapter;
```

and instantiated in the onCreate method of the activity like so:

```
    chatAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.fragment_group_chat);
```

I'll be setting default contents for the adapter when I get to that point.

Comment: It *might produce* a NullPointerException is only a warning because findViewById can return null. Anyways, try to avoid static variables too. If the Fragment has the ListView, put the adapter there too

Comment: why are you using getView()? is it inside a fragment? replace with: `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);` & `ListView list  = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.taskList)`. Or have a look [here](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) for binding views easily

Comment: You can add a getter method(getList) to your activity which returns the list.
And from your fragment you can get the reference to it by
(ActivityName)getActivity().getList()
But as @cricket_007 said, it is better to avoid these types of static variables

Answer (score 0):

Lint is just warning you that you aren't checking for a null reference before using it.

If you change your code to:

```
    ListView list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tasksList);
    if (list != null) {
        list.setAdapter(GroupContentActivity.tasksAdapter);
    }
```

the warning will go away.